# Query optimization in ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I created a code in ColdFusion to load data from Users and UsersTransactions tables and display it in a table. However, my queries is taking long time to run.

```
<!--- This return about 250 records --->
<cfquery name="getUsers" datasource="db">
    Select * From Users Where test = 5
</cfquery>

<!--- Loop to display the Users info --->
<cfloop query="getUsers">
    <cfset SpecialDebit = 0 />
    <cfset TotalDebit = 0 />
    <cfset SpecialCredit = 0 />
    <cfset TotalCredit = 0 />

    <!--- Loop to get Users Balance --->
    <cfquery name="getUsersTransactions" datasource="db">
        SELECT * FROM UsersTransactions , TransactionTypes, ChargeTypes 
        Where UsersTransactions.TransactionTypeID=TransactionTypes.TransactionTypeID 
        AND ChargeTypes.ChargeTypeID=UsersTransactions.ChargeTypeID  
        AND UsersTransactions.UserID=#getUsers.UserID#
    </cfquery>
    <cfloop query="getUsersTransactions">
        <cfif TransactionTypeID EQ "1"> <!--- This means it's a debit --->
            <cfif ChargeTypeID EQ "6"> <!-- This means its a special debit --->
                <cfset SpecialDebit += TransactionAmount />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset TotalDebit += TransactionAmount />
            </cfif>     
        </cfif>
        <cfif TransactionTypeID EQ "2"> <!--- This means it's a credit --->
            <cfif ChargeTypeID EQ "6"> <!-- This means its a special credit --->
                <cfset SpecialCredit += TransactionAmount />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset TotalCredit += TransactionAmount />
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset UserSpecialBalance = SpecialDebit - SpecialCredit />
    <cfset UserBalance = TotalDebit - TotalCredit />

    <!--- Display User's data in a table with Column Special Balance and User Balance --->
    .
    .
    .

</cfloop>
```

What is taking long time is the loop for the "getUsersTransactions" query. Is there a way to make these queries run faster?

**Update:**

Data sample for one User:

```
User.UserID = 10
```

It will have, for example, 6 records in UsersTransactions

```
             Transaction
#   UserID   TypeID      ChargeTypeID    TransactionAmount
1   10       1           6               25
2   10       1           6               17
3   10       1           1               50
4   10       2           1               12
5   10       2           6               7
6   10       2           6               18
```

In this case I have:

- 2 "Special Debit" (records 1 and 2): SpecialDebit = `25+17 = 42`
- 1 Normal Debit (record 3): TotalDebit = `50`
- 1 Normal Credit (record 4): TotalCredit = `12`
- 2 Special Credit (records 5 and 6): SpecialCredit = `7+18 = 25`

Comment: Rather than looping over queries and hammering your database, it would be much better (and probably much faster) to rewrite the query and then loop over all of the results. Also, there are a lot of `cfif`s inside that loop. You are doing a lot of processing for these results. Most of that can actually be done inside the query itself.

Comment: Lastly, use `JOIN`s instead of the older comma syntax for your queries.

Comment: Thanks... I got the JOIN, but how can I get the results without looping over the queries?

Comment: And looking at your code, it doesn't appear that you are using anything from `TransactionTypes` or `ChargeTypes` (unless it's shown somewhere in the user data display).  Those tables can probably be dropped from the query.

Comment: And another note, with `SELECT *` from joined tables, `TransactionTypeID` and `ChargeTypeID` aren't necessarily coming from a specific table. In other situations this could result in unexpected data returned. Be explicit.

Comment: "how can I get the results without looping over the queries" By using JOIN's as suggested. The new "join" query would return all of the user and transaction data.  Looping to *output* results is ok. Running a new querying for every user record isn't. @Shawn - you should post those tips as an answer.

Comment: But 1 result from getUsers will have multiples records into UsersTransactions, so is it possible to join and do everything in one query?

Comment: Can you provide some example data of what you're working with? And what you're expected output will look like?

Comment: Sure. I just added one data example

Comment: Any chance your query is returning things that are not of TransactionTypeID ( 1 "debit" / 2 "credit" ) is there like type (3 "cash") ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestions above essentially amounted to grabbing the data you need for all users in the query and then outputting those results instead of looping to rerun a query for a user. I've added a stab at using the query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9976d/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( userid int, name varchar(10), test int ) ;
INSERT INTO users (userid, name, test)
VALUES 
    ( 1, 'Bill', 5 ) 
  , ( 2, 'Tex', 3 )
  , ( 3, 'Rufus', 5 )
  , ( 4, 'SilentBob', 5 )
  , ( 5, 'Jay', 5 )
;

CREATE TABLE UsersTransactions ( UserID int, TransactionTypeID int, ChargeTypeID int, TransactionAmount int ) ;
INSERT INTO UsersTransactions ( UserID, TransactionTypeID, ChargeTypeID, TransactionAmount )
VALUES 
    ( 1, 1, 6, 2 )  /* Special Debit */
  , ( 1, 1, 1, 5 )  /* Normal Debit */
  , ( 2, 1, 6, 20 )
  , ( 2, 1, 1, 20 )
  , ( 3, 1, 6, 30 )
  , ( 3, 1, 1, 30 )
  , ( 1, 2, 6, 5 )  /* Special Credit */
  , ( 1, 2, 1, 5 )  /* Special Credit */
  , ( 2, 2, 6, 20 )
  , ( 2, 2, 1, 20 )
  , ( 3, 2, 6, 20 )
  , ( 3, 2, 1, 20 )
  , ( 5, 1, 1, 500 )  /* Normal Debit */
;

CREATE TABLE TransactionTypes ( TransactionTypeID int, Description varchar(10) ) ;
INSERT INTO TransactionTypes VALUES ( 1, 'Debit' ), ( 2, 'Credit' ) ;

CREATE TABLE ChargeTypes ( ChargeTypeID int, Description varchar(10) ) ;
INSERT INTO ChargeTypes VALUES ( 1, 'Regular' ), ( 6, 'Special' ) ;
```

**Initial Query Example**: *NOTE: This can be further optimized.*

```
SELECT u.userid
  , u.name
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 1  AND ut.ChargeTypeID = 1 THEN ut.TransactionAmount END) AS NormalDebit
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 1  AND ut.ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN ut.TransactionAmount END) AS SpecialDebit
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 2  AND ut.ChargeTypeID = 1 THEN ut.TransactionAmount END) AS NormalCredit
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 2  AND ut.ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN ut.TransactionAmount END) AS SpecialCredit
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 1  THEN ut.TransactionAmount WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 2  THEN ut.TransactionAmount * -1 END) AS TotalAmount
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersTransactions ut ON u.userid = ut.UserID 
INNER JOIN TransactionTypes tt ON ut.TransactionTypeID = tt.TransactionTypeID  
INNER JOIN ChargeTypes ct ON ut.ChargeTypeID = ct.ChargeTypeID
WHERE u.test = 5
GROUP BY u.userID
ORDER BY u.userID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9976d/1/0)**:

```
| userid |      name | SpecialBalance | TotalBalance |
|--------|-----------|----------------|--------------|
|      1 |      Bill |             -3 |           -3 |
|      3 |     Rufus |             10 |           20 |
|      4 | SilentBob |              0 |            0 |
|      5 |       Jay |              0 |          500 |
```

This outputs the necessary fields for UserIDs 1, 3, 4 and 5 that are test=5 filtered. Since there doesn't appear to be any data coming from the tables `TransactionTypes` and `ChargeTypes`, those `INNER JOIN`s can be removed to significantly speed up the query.

So when you get to CF, you can simplify the query. Try:

```
<cfquery name="getUsersTransactions" datasource="db">
    SELECT s1.userid
      , s1.name
      , ( s1.SpecialDebit - s1.SpecialCredit ) AS SpecialBalance
      , ( (s1.NormalDebit + s1.SpecialDebit) - (s1.NormalCredit + s1.SpecialCredit) ) AS TotalBalance
    FROM (
      SELECT u.userid
        , u.name
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 1  AND ut.ChargeTypeID = 1 THEN ut.TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS NormalDebit
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 1  AND ut.ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN ut.TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS SpecialDebit
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 2  AND ut.ChargeTypeID = 1 THEN ut.TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS NormalCredit
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ut.TransactionTypeID = 2  AND ut.ChargeTypeID = 6 THEN ut.TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS SpecialCredit
      FROM users u
      LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersTransactions ut ON u.userid = ut.UserID 
      WHERE u.test = 5
      GROUP BY u.userID
    ) s1
</cfquery>

<table>
<th>UserID</th>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>UserSpecialBalance</th>
<th>UserBalance</th>
<cfoutput query="getUsersTransactions">
    <!--- Build out the table rows in here--->
    <tr>
        <td>#getUsersTransactions.userID#</td>
        <td>#getUsersTransactions.name#</td>
        <td>#getUsersTransactions.SpecialBalance#</td>
        <td>#getUsersTransactions.TotalBalance#</td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

*NOTE: Adding the `ELSE 0` to the `CASE` statements will filter out the `NULL` values in the query that will break the summing. CF will still display those results as a blank, but the data could be wrong.*

Comment: Very true. And then `ELSE 0` would definitely affect those rows, since they would need _something_ to sum.

Comment: I added the `LEFT OUTER` and the `ELSE 0` to the queries. It makes it much more failure-proof, though it can change the intended operation of the query. Other edge-cases should also be checked.

Answer (score 3):

I would use this sort of program flow.  It represents the general idea.  The details are up to you.

Step 1 - Run a single query to get all your data.  Sort it by user ID because you are going to use CF's group attribute.

```
<cfquery name="data">
select userID, field1, field2, etc
from users u join UsersTransactions ut on u.UserId = ut.userID
etc
where whatever
order by userID
</cfquery>
```

Step 2 - Start outputting data at the user level.  Then for each user, do your calculations and output the result.

```
<cfoutput query="data" group="userID">
#username# etc
<cfset totalCredit = totalDebit = specialCredit = specialDebit = 0>

<!--- now do the math for each user --->
<cfoutput>
<cfscript>
if (whatever)  totalCredit += something;
etc
</cfscript>
</cfoutput>
<!--- display these variables --->
#totalCredit#
</cfoutput>
```

You can read more about the group attribute of the cfoutput tag in the [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff6.html).

Comment: If there's a limited number of types, you could just calculate the sums in sql too, using `case`.